# How to use CUDA with C to speed up a piece of C code？

Tags: performance, optimization, cuda

This is the device code I have written so far.

```
__global__ void syndrom(int *d_s, int *d_cx) {
int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + 1;
int t2 = 5460;
int N_BCH = 16383;
if (tid <= t2) {
    d_s[Usetid] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N_BCH; j ++) {
        if (d_cx[j] != 0) {
            d_s[tid] ^= d_alpha_to[(tid * j) % N_BCH];
        }
    }
    d_s[tid] = d_index_of[d_s[tid]];
}
```

}

I call it in the host

```
dim3 grid(96);
dim3 block(256);
```

But the speed is not very good, I want to get help. Thanks.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. What is `Usetid` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a [Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which you are expected to provide here on StackOverflow (for example - what `is d_alpha_to`?), but I can still make a few suggestions:

1. Use more threads instead of having each thread iterate a very large number of times. They way GPU work parallelizes is saturating the processors with threads which are ready to perform more computation.
2. Don't operate on (the same place in) global memory repeatedly. Put `d_s[tid]` in a local variable (which will be placed in a register), work on it there, and when you're done, write it back. Accessing global memory is obviously much much slower than accessing registers.
3. Decorate your pointers with `__restrict__` (and make d_cx a `const` pointer). Read more about `__restrict__` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict).

Comment: d_alpha_to and d_index_of is a array, the length is 16383.

Comment: @worldhello: Here you go.